# American Airlines size 26 will I fit in the seat?

Tags: air-travel, seating, american-airlines

I am 5’7 and 370 pounds with wide hips. I flew Alaska airlines back in 2017 and I barely fit, but I’m seeing mixed reviews for American Airlines economy seats. Should I just purchase a second seat?

That's 170 cm tall and 168 kilograms.

Comment: Note that AA have many different aircraft, which may have different seat widths. You may want to lookup the details for your flight on a site like [seatguru.com](http://seatguru.com)

Comment: Regardless of what the exact rules and what the enforcement might be, buying two seats would be by far the safest and most comfortable option. Even if you can get away with one, it will NOT be a fun experience.

Comment: You should realize that StackExchange has global reach. Saying _I am 5’7, 370_ and a size 26 is meaningless to nearly everyone but Americans (and, I suspect most American men don't understand the significance of _size 26_). Next time, add some units (like ft. in. and lb). Not sure how to make size 26 make any sense, though

Comment: @Flydog57: "Size 26" makes little sense to me as an American man, and IMHO it means nothing at all to anyone. Women's sizes are [basically just made up numbers](https://www.vox.com/2016/8/3/12353906/womens-clothing-sizes-vanity-sizing), and men's sizes are normally two separate numbers in inches (waist/leg).

Comment: @Kevin as an American I'm also not sure what is meant by "size 26". Is that waist size?

Comment: @BruceWayne: Assuming it's a women's size: It means it is smaller than a size 27 and larger than a size 25. Beyond that, you just have to go into the store and try it on. It makes no logical sense, but unfortunately it's how the industry works.

Answer (score 10):

According to https://www.plussizetraveltoo.com/2022/02/north-american-customer-of-size-policies/ the seats on American Airlines planes are 17 inches wide in the Main Cabin. Main Cabin Extra is no bigger, however Premium Economy and Business range from 18.5 inches to 21.9 inches. The seatbelt on American Airlines planes is 45 to 47 inches wide.

American Airlines *Extra Space During Travel* policy says:

“If a customer needs extra space outside a single seat to travel safely, another seat is required. We encourage customers to address all seating needs when booking.

- When you call to book, Reservations will make sure you get 2 adjacent seats at the same rate.
- If you didn’t book an extra seat in advance, ask an airport agent to find out if 2 adjacent seats are available.
- You may be offered a seat in a higher class of service that may provide more space; in this case, you’ll be responsible for the fare difference.
- If accommodations can’t be made on your original flight, you can buy seats on a different flight at the same price as your original seats.”

Source: https://www.aa.com/i18n/travel-info/special-assistance/special-assistance.jsp#extraspace